# PHPUnit test dies

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a PHPUnit test that is killing the execution of PHPUnit and I'm unable to figure out why.  Executing `phpunit --debug` shows the output:

```
....
Starting test 'Delegates\AggregateGeneratorDelegateTest::testRunWithFalseArgumentsShouldSucceed'.
.
Starting test 'Delegates\AggregateGeneratorDelegateTest::testRunWithValidArgumentsShouldFail'.
.
Starting test 'Delegates\AggregateGeneratorDelegateTest::testUpdateRoutesFile'.
.
Starting test 'Delegates\GeneratorDelegateTest::testRunWithInvalidConfigAndFails'.
MacBook-Pro:blacksmith myUser$
```

I've searched the code and I can't find any `exit` or `die`'s in there.  It began with the changes I made today where I implemented the [`OptionReader`](https://github.com/bkuhl/blacksmith/blob/develop/src/lib/Console/OptionReader.php) class.  Unfortunately, I don't know exactly which change caused this.

All source code is available on GitHub: https://github.com/bkuhl/blacksmith/tree/develop

I've tried increasing PHP's memory limit and ensuring both `display_errors = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL`.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can diagnose what the issue is?  When I comment out this one test, it simply dies on the next one.

Comment: Do you have any PHP errors in the log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I searched thoroughly for `exit`/`die`, I didn't think to look for `@`.  I ended up finding a `@$genFactory->make(...)` which was causing things to die without any description.